# Bloginfo hook - can it be more precise?

Tags: hooks, bloginfo

From the codex, regarding filter hooks:

```
bloginfo_url  
applied to the the output of bloginfo("url"), bloginfo("directory") and bloginfo("home") before returning the information.
```

Is there a way I can specify that a bit more precise? So that I can hook something only to `bloginfo("url")` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that, using the additional variable in the Filter Functions.

The Filter `bloginfo_url` uses the `$show` parameter (the parameter you use when calling `bloginfo`) and passes it to `apply_filters`.

So hooking into `bloginfo_url` should be no problem, you just have to make a switch inside the function, and it only applies to e.g. `url` .

This would be the Code for you:

```
add_filter('bloginfo_url', 'f711_bloginfo_url_filter', 10, 2 );
```

It tells you where you hook into, the callback function, the priority in which it is applied compared to other filters, and the number of arguments that can be passed to the function. This is your important part, as 1 is the standard value.

In the Callback Function:

```
function f711_bloginfo_url_filter( $output, $show ) {

    if ( $show == 'url' ) {
        $output = "this";//whatever you want to do with it
    }

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Super cool thank you! Do you have a link where this is documented? In the Codex page for `bloginfo` `$show` is mentioned and in the page for `add_filter` the integer is mentioned, but how do I know exactly which int targets what property?

Comment: If it is not documented on the Codex, you may have to look into the Sourcecode for the specific filter. There you can see how much Arguments are passed on, and this should determine the value of the second integer you use to hook your filter function. Afterwards they are used in the same order as they are passed to the filter. If you look at `general-template.php` in the `wp-includes` you can find this filter, and I'm sure you understand better what I am talking about ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I can't find it in that file, although I think I know what you mean. Is it that function at line 405? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L405 I just want to really understand how this works, because for example I can't hook that function into `home_url` or `site_url`because I don't know the parameters.

Comment: No problem. This is the right file, and you are in the right function, but you have to look at the lines where the filters are applied. [Line 491](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L491) is the correct one, and of course 493. Here you can see that the filter for `bloginfo_url` is applied, with the two parameters `$output` and `$show`, the latter being defined before (starting at line 405). Everything clear so far? Don't hesitate to ask if not :)

Comment: Ah ok cool, now I understand it. Thank you very much!